# DiscordJS v13 send to specific channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I am trying to send an embed to a different channel than the command was used in as a log channel how ever I have tried a few different methods however where I am at now is the error i get is `qChann.send is not a function` it is yelling at the .send part.

This is the part referenced in index.js **Yes I know it is bad practice to reference and export from main file but I am desperate for a solution**

```
client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log('Online');

    const qChann = client.channels.cache.get('960425106964885535');

    console.log(qChann);
})
```

The second part is in a command file call **deposit.js**
It uses a 2 part collector **ignore date and time stuff thats from express**
I am also using mongoDB and it works completely fine how ever that last little statement is giving me a hard time `qChann.send({embed: steelEmbed});` also qChann is included as `const qChann = require('../index');`

```
if (collected.content.toLowerCase() === 'steel') {
                message.reply('Enter the amount youd like to deposit');
                collector.stop('user entered steel');

                const steelCollector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({
                    filter,
                    max: 1,
                    time: 1000 * 20,
                  });
                
                steelCollector.on('collect', async (collected) => {
                    const steelAmount = collected.content;

                    await steelSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                        $inc: {
                            steel: +steelAmount,
                        }
                    })
                 
                    steelNewCount = await steelSchema.findOne({steelSchema}, {_id: 0});
                    
                    const steelEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('#4278f5')
                    .setTitle(`Ammo11 Stash Update`)
                    .setDescription(`Steel Count Updated`)
                    .addField(`Stash Updated`, `by <@${message.author.id}>`, true)
                    .addField(`Date Log`, `${date} / ${month} / ${year}`, true)
                    .addField(`Steel Deposited`, `${steelAmount}`, true)
                    .addField(`New Steel Count`, `${steelNewCount}`, true )
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter({text:'THIS MESSAGE IS NOT TO BE DELETED'});
                    
                qChann.send({embed: steelEmbed});

                })
                
                
                
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define channel and then export it. You didn't export so you can't take it from another file as i know.

```js
// outside of events

const qChann = client.channels.cache.get("960425106964885535")
module.exports = { qChann }
```

After this edit on your main file, you can access your channel with importing it with require in your command files.